# A little help on fieldset and form tags imbrication

Tags: html, forms

I am currently writing a Java EE web-app using JSP's and I have a question regarding HTML tags.

I use fieldsets to properly structurate my forms on the main page and find myself perplexed and was wondering if the following was legal:

```
<fieldset id="FieldMain">
    <form method="post" action="servletA">
        <input name="a" type="text" />
        <fieldset id="FieldA">
            <input name="b" type="text" />
            <input name="c" type="text" />
            <input name="d" type="submit" value="Go for A" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="servletB">
        <fieldset id="FieldB">
            <input name="e" type="text" />
            <input name="f" type="text" />
            <input name="g" type="submit" value="Go for B" />
        </fieldset
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

With the desired result being that when clicking the "Go for A" button it takes into account the field a, b and c (a being outside of the fieldset fieldA but inside the form A tag) while clicking go for B only takes fields e and f.

In other words, if I use field sets, can I have several forms in one single fieldset tag ? And can I have some fields outside of any fieldset tag as long as it is in the form tag ?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's legal, but it's not entended to do this

> The FIELDSET element allows authors to group thematically related
>   controls and labels. Grouping controls makes it easier for users to
>   understand their purpose while simultaneously facilitating tabbing
>   navigation for visual user agents and speech navigation for
>   speech-oriented user agents. The proper use of this element makes
>   documents more accessible.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.10

> As far as I remember form past discussions: it's legal according to
>   the letter of the standard and the DTD also makes it valid where a
>   block element is valid. Now as to intend, that's harder to determine,
>   it feels to me to be intended to be used in forms only. I don't know
>   why it got the far wider scope.
>
> Also note that -despite the CSS standard not stating it should- a
>   fieldset creates a new stacking context (logical if you think about it
>   and the default way it's rendered, but not mentioned in the standard
>   AFAIK).
>
> IMHO extensive use of it outside forms and/or reliance on the new
>   stacking context are dangerous if you want future proof code.

source: http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3915579.htm

Comment: Okay, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. it seemed to me that it was the simplest solution given the pattern I was given for the H-C Interface as I am entirely recoding a previously (and poorly) written (in PHP) app that was never deployed and I do intend producing future-proof code as my app is to be deployed. Thank you